# Replicate number_format

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to replicate number_format() (which exists in php).

For instance

```
 1234 => 1,234
 10000 => 10,000
 1000000 => 100,000
```

The language i'm using does not support lists/arrays/regex, so i'm open to any suggestions. My previous code only appeared to work for numbers such as 10000000 (10,000,000), but as soon as i used a number such as 1000 it gave 10,00 sadly.

An example in php will work fine, so then I can translate it.

Thanks

Comment: What language *are* you using?

Comment: ? What language?? And what can it do? (count the figures/chr? if it has >= 4 insert comma after every 3 figures. Can it do it?)

Comment: You could always take a look at the PHP source code for number_format(), which is written in C

Comment: What language doesn't support lists, arrays, or regular expressions? Are you coding 8086 assembler? What does your existing code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version of Kae Verens' function.

```
function number_format($num){
  $num=(string)$num;
  $len=strlen($num);
  $newnum='';
  for ($i=0; $i<$len; ++$i) {
    if (($i%3==0) && $i) {
      $newnum=','.$newnum;
    }
    $newnum=$num[$len-$i-1].$newnum;
  }
  return $newnum;
}
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/vhJJw6ED When I use this, it doesn't work, unless i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @user551841 I edited the code. I had to cast $num to a string.

Comment: this was enough for me to convert it to the language I required, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

another method:

```
function number_format($num){
  $len=strlen( (string)$num );
  $newnum='';
  for ($i=$len; $i>=0; --$i) {
    $newnum=$num{$i}.$newnum;
    if (!$i%3 && $i) {
      $newnum=','.$newnum;
    }
  }
  return (int)$newnum;
}
```

Comment: That's not producing the expected output. If it would produce the right result you shouldn't cast it back to an `(int)` because that would strip away the added commas. Also the logic is too simple, and the boolean handling is wrong (`!` negates the `$i` before the modulo is applied). Also it would need to count the position in reverese *from* the end. It's useful as general approach example however :]

Comment: whoops ;-) obviously threw it straight out of my head into the comment. you missed that $i should start at $len-1. the code has problems, but the idea behind it would work.

Comment: The example code doesn't work, even with the modification that you said it needed

Answer (score 0):

something like this may work (not tested):

```
function number_format($num){
  $num=(string)$num;
  while (preg_match('/[^,][0-9]{3}[,$]/', $num) {
    $num=preg_replace('/([^,])([0-9]{3})[,$]/', '\1,\2', $num);
  }
  $num=preg_replace('/^([0-9]),/', '\1', $num);
  return $num;
}
```

Comment: "The language i'm using does not support lists/arrays/regex, so i'm open to any suggestions." Thanks for your suggestion though! :(

Comment: hmm... should cast $num back to a number before returning. also, will only work with integers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$number = 10000000;
echo number_format($number, 0, '', ',');
```